# Prevent GMSMarker from repositioning camera view on tap

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am creating a custom marker like below,

```
let am = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.213232, 144.332233))
am.title = "some title"
am.icon = UIImage(named: "marker_pointer")
am.map = self.map
```

The above marker on tap, repositions the camera view and places itself in the centre of the map.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: How did you initialize the GMSMapView?

Comment: @bennegeek Just like its mentioned in the docs, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map

Comment: Because mine doesnt recenter the map when I add a marker.

Comment: @bennegeek On tap of marker it doesn't recenter? Does your marker have tilte property set? And is it using a custom icon?

Comment: @Rao when I tap on the marker it keeps moving the camera to the top and yes I am using a custom icon

Comment: This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38160021/3220708

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out (from @Craig's comment above) that there is a way to do this with `GMSMapView` delegate method implementation:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        mapView.selectedMarker = marker
        return true
}
```